# What is an alternative word for 'repercussions' that has a positive denotation rather than a negative denotation / connotation?

Tags: vocabulary

The relevant [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/repercussion) definition of **repercussion** [n] is:

> 1 (usually repercussions): An unintended consequence of an event or
>   action, especially an unwelcome one.

The caveat means that a negative denotation is often intended / inferred, and surely that there is at least a negative connotation. Is there a word with the meaning 'positive consequences'?

Comment: The meaning of *repercussions* is not "a series of bad events" - so your question is not clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - according to the OED the meaning of 'repercussion'   is "*...A return of any kind of action, a responsive act, a resulting effect or implication; an **undesired or unintended** consequence*".  This is how I understand the word - usually suggesting something unwanted.

Comment: @DipeshBhanadari Please provide some context to your question - as it stands, it's too broad and there are many possible answers, for example: rewards, benefits, perks, bonuses, blessings, advantages and others.

Comment: @Dan I do know what the meaning of *repercussion* is, thank you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - If *a repercussion* is "an undesired consequence" (OED)  it seems reasonable to me to paraphrase '*repercussions*' as "*a series of bad events*", doesn't it?

Comment: @Dan There are many instances of a series of bad events that are not repercussions of anything. And not all repercussions are a series of bad events. OP's original question equated the two and that's why it wasn't clear. It's still not clear now.

Comment: @Dan Just because a consequence is "undesired or unintended" does not imply that it is bad or negative. It just means it was not the intended outcome. The untended consequence of her asking the price of the vase was that it was gifted to her.

Comment: Both 'The meaning of repercussions is not "a series of bad events" ' and 'a repercussion is "an undesired consequence" ' are selective statements and thus violate the Gricean maxim of quantity (and probably that of quality too). The word has different and partly conflicting senses. And certainly carries at least a connotation of bad consequences.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - thank you for introducing me to Gricean maxims.  I especially like 'perspicuity'.

Comment: I've edited here, but do you want Is there a word with the meaning '**unintended** positive consequences'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed, but certainly, "carries at least a connotation of bad consequences" is not equivalent to - always means bad consequences. To speak to my point.

Comment: @Alaska man I was addressing solely michael.hor257k's first comment and Dan's second: the quotes make that clear. I don't see how your 'but' is correct. And your 'means' is ambiguous. 'Denotes', 'connotes', or 'means that there must be'?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider ***fluke***.

ODO:

> **[fluke](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fluke)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> An unlikely chance occurrence, especially a surprising piece of luck.
>   ‘their triumph was no fluke’

Macmillan:

> **[fluke](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fluke#fluke_4)**
>   *NOUN* [COUNTABLE] *INFORMAL*
>
> something that happens unexpectedly because of an accident or good
>   luck
>
> I think their last win was just a fluke.

Also, ***serendipity***.

ODO:

> **[serendipity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/serendipity)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> The occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or
>   beneficial way.
>
> ‘a series of small serendipities’

Answer (score -2):

The ***knock-on*** advantages.

*Knock-on* - Being a secondary or indirect consequence of another action, occurrence, or event (OED).

Or,

*the **consequential** advantages.*

*Consequential* - Of the nature of a consequence or sequel; following, esp. as an effect or result (OED).

Comment: 'Positive consequences' is better if more than one word is allowed. And Lawrence came up with 'benefits'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - My answer is offered as a possible solution. If you think your ideas 'better' why not post them as an answer? To my mind, 'benefit' is not the operative word here (and I have deleted it from my answer). The sense sought by the OP, as he expressed it, is not 'benefit' (unqualified), but 'positive consequences'. Your 'better' solution simply echoes the OP - who is wanting ideas other than his own. – Dan 13 mins ago